# get the values of the options in the dropdown after moving them from one to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 drop downs and I can move the objects from one to another using the buttons. I want to get the updated values after I am done with moving them from one drop down to another. the values in the array is coming out to be null.

How can I get the updated value of all the options in an array. I need to pass the updated values to the controller from one function like function **AddFiles(iniIdArray,afterIdArray)**

http://jsfiddle.net/678hmujh/1/

```
var varInitialId = document.getElementById('iniId');
   for (i = 0; i < varInitialId.options.length; i++) {
         iniIdArray[i] = varInitialId.options[i].value; 
    }

    var varAfterId = document.getElementById('afterId');
    for (i = 0; i < varAfterId.options.length; i++) {
         afterIdArray[i] = varAfterId.options[i].value;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use map: http://jsfiddle.net/678hmujh/4/

```
$('#listButton').on('click', function() {
    var first = $('#iniId option').map(function(){ return this.value; });
    var second = $('#afterId option').map(function(){ return this.value; });
    console.log( first.toArray() );
    console.log( second.toArray() );
});
```

By doing first.toArray() or second.toArray() you can get a basic javascript array of what was built.

Comment: I want to pass the value as an arguments to the function like I said AddFiles(iniIdArray,afterIdArray) so iniIdArray and afterIdArray should contain the updated value not after click a button or something.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding the issue then.  You said you needed to get the updated values of the select.  My example was just to show that you could do so with .map();  The event handler that invokes this can change.  However now your saying you need to pass 'the value' to the function, instead of 'the values'.

Comment: its values only. so in the function I ll pass all the values of an array as one parameter and other values of an array as other parameter.

Comment: Right, so $(selectorToOptions).map() as used above will return a list of all the values from the select.  It looks like map is returning an object instead of a raw list though, so let me update it.

Comment: yes thats working but one last question as I will not have any button like list so the values are not in first.to Array even if I have made the first as global. I will just have one function in which I will be passing the values after making changes to the options directly without clicking any button so how can I do that.

Comment: So the question you have to ask yourself then is when should it happen?  That will tell you where/how you should bind to do the mapping logic to get your data.  Essentially, what has to happen on the page for you to know you need to execute that function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77046/discussion-between-psdebugger-and-taplar).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select#iniId > option').each(function() {
    $(this).text(); //is your option text
    $(this).val(); //is your option value
});
```